# Pull latest version from nexus

Tags: jenkins, jar, nexus, continuous-delivery

For example I have pushed 3 jar versions to nexus, v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2. How can I pull version "v1.1" from nexus?

For general knowledge, I am using Jenkins and trying to make Continuous Delivery. So I need to get a specific version from nexus to create a Docker image with that jar.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building them from maven projects each nexus app (app in nexus) will have a metadata file, there you can pull the latest.

> com/orgname/appname/maven-metadata.xml

Note that by design, latest isn't the most recently built one in some cases. If you want the most recent one, you can take the list from that .xml and grab the one at the bottom.